# system freeze on monitor wake-up after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: nvidia, kernel, 16.04, multiple-monitors

I have nvidia gtx 980 (driver v. 364.19), MSI X99S MB, i7-5820k 32GB DDR4 ram.

My setup is 3 4k monitors (on DP-0, DP-2 and Dp-4)

After my monitors go to sleep (the computer is not asleep) then when I try to wake up the monitors, the system load gradually goes up and it keeps going up. There is no increase in cpu (ocasionaly xorg cpu jups to 100%). I am not able to remote login. I have to force shutdown with the power button and restart the computer. I did not have this issue with 15.10.

I am not able to find any meaningful error. I have tried many things that were suggested in in the web.

I have nvidia modesetting set to 0. I think the kernel ignores that.

```
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-23-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=34f125fb-0746-481f-94de-974b47825aab ro nouveau.modeset=0 nvidia.modeset=0 nvidia-drm.modeset=0 nomodeset
```

But then I get this boot message:

```
nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  364.19  Tue Apr 19 14:15:03 PDT 2016
```

I am looking for a workaround. I think this is kernel/nvidia driver bug possibly related to modesettings. I do not have the issue with driver 355.11 (prior to mode settings)

I would like to add that I found the following in the system log file at the time of crash. If I understand it correctly it points to an issues with nvidia_modese

```
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#5 stuck for 22s! [Xorg:24701]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: Modules linked in: ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 ebtable_filter ip6table_filter nfnetlink_queue nfnetlink_log xt_multiport nf_log_ip
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  nf_conntrack_snmp xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ip
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  snd_seq_device snd_hda_core snd_hwdep saa7164 snd_pcm tveeprom dvb_core videodev snd_timer media snd lpc_ich mei_me soundcore m
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: CPU: 5 PID: 24701 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P           OE   4.6.0-040600rc7-generic #201605081830
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: Hardware name: MSI MS-7885/X99A SLI PLUS(MS-7885), BIOS 1.90 10/30/2015
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: task: ffff880718d0da00 ti: ffff88072467c000 task.ti: ffff88072467c000
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc0cc09f0>]  [<ffffffffc0cc09f0>] _nv001065kms+0x0/0x70 [nvidia_modeset]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff88072467fad0  EFLAGS: 00000296
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: RAX: ffffffffc0d0cf60 RBX: ffff88016afe0c08 RCX: 00000000002afb7f
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: RDX: ffff880121f67dc8 RSI: ffff88016afe0c08 RDI: ffff88010a13ba08
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: RBP: ffff88010a13ba08 R08: 0000000000019e80 R09: ffffffffc0c6f4ae
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: R10: ffffea00221e8140 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff880851bf7008
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: R13: ffff88072d6b8008 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: FS:  00007f00a6d47a00(0000) GS:ffff88089f340000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: CR2: 000055768785bb6c CR3: 00000006e00d6000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: Stack:
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  ffffffffc0cb94bd 000000000009bd1b 00000000f3b3ef4c ffff88089792a7c8
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  ffff880851bf6808 ffff880851bf6c08 ffff88072d6b8008 0000000000000000
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  ffffffffc0cad546 ffff880851bf6850 0000000000000000 ffff880851bf6c08
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel: Call Trace:
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffffc0cb94bd>] ? _nv000697kms+0x20d/0x2c0 [nvidia_modeset]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffffc0cad546>] ? _nv001728kms+0x56/0xd0 [nvidia_modeset]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffffc0ca12bc>] ? _nv000007kms+0x3ec/0x400 [nvidia_modeset]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffffc0ca2944>] ? _nv001976kms+0x1674/0x22b0 [nvidia_modeset]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffffc0c6f3e0>] ? nvkms_alloc+0x50/0x60 [nvidia_modeset]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffffc0c70520>] ? _nv000324kms+0x30/0x30 [nvidia_modeset]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffffc0c7054e>] ? _nv000333kms+0x2e/0x40 [nvidia_modeset]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffffc0c710e1>] ? nvKmsIoctl+0x161/0x1e0 [nvidia_modeset]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffffc0c6fd85>] ? nvkms_ioctl_common+0x45/0x80 [nvidia_modeset]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffffc0c6fe31>] ? nvkms_ioctl+0x71/0xa0 [nvidia_modeset]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffffc01fc080>] ? nvidia_frontend_compat_ioctl+0x40/0x50 [nvidia]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffffc01fc09e>] ? nvidia_frontend_unlocked_ioctl+0xe/0x10 [nvidia]
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffff81237721>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0xa1/0x5b0
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffff81094294>] ? restore_altstack+0x24/0x40
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffff81237ca9>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
May 22 09:34:25 i7-5820k kernel:  [<ffffffff81845476>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1e/0xa8
```

Any ideas for workaround or identifying the issue will be appreciated.

Comment: In the nvidia web site I found this statement referring to all the resent drivers including  the new 367 driver. "* Resuming from suspend may not be reliable on GeForce GTX 9xx boards in some configurations."  I am looking for any workaround for this issue.